# How to get return value of const function from website?

Tags: web3js, contract-invocation, dapp-development

Ok so my issue is that my website is hosted using a 3rd party service so I am unable to run geth on the same server as my site. However, I also have a separate VPS which I can setup nodejs and a web3js page or geth to interact with my contracts.

My goal is to call a constant function in my contract and display the result on my website. Is there a way for me to interact with my VPS from my website and call constant functions? Is there a better way to solve my issue?

If I run a node on my vps, am I able to use web3js on my site to call functions? What about transactions?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Run a Parity or Geth node hosted somewhere on the internet and expose the JSON-RPC interface to the internet (HTTP port 8545).  Make sure this node does *not* have any keys attached to it, you won't need them for your usage.

From your website, you'll want to do an HTTP post over the JSON-RPC to the [`eth_call` method](https://github.com/paritytech/parity/wiki/JSONRPC-eth-module#eth_call).  You can see the curl example at that link for details on how to structure the call.

Rather than trying to manually construct the parameters however, I recommend you use a helper library like web3, ethjs, or parity.js.  You can see a full example of how to call a constant function in the [ethjs documentation](https://github.com/ethjs/ethjs#usage) if you choose to go that route.  Just change the ABI to match your method's ABI (you can get this from a tool like remix or Solidity compiler output) and change the HTTP address to that of your node.

Comment: How do I make sure there are now keys attached to the node?

Comment: If it is a new node then it won't have any keys.  Just make sure not to add any and you'll be fine.  :). If you do add keys, you can remove them (differs by client).

Comment: Ok, one last question. If I wanted to call a transaction rather than a constant, I would need keys. Is there a secure way to do this? Such that users of my site wont be able to access my keys / call transactions?

Comment: You can sign a transaction on a server you control (securing your keys in whatever way makes sense to you) and then send that transaction to your public node.  The act of signing a transaction and submitting a transaction to the blockchain can be separate actions, doing them at the same time using keys stored in the node is merely a convenience.  To do this you will want to use https://github.com/paritytech/parity/wiki/JSONRPC-eth-module#eth_sendrawtransaction after you have signed the transaction on your secured server.

Answer (score 0):

Not sure if this is what you're looking for, and it is most certainly not a decentralized solution, but you might want to look into a service called Infura. It provides access to a node's RPC interface and does so at a very high level of availability. It's totally centralized, but that's a different issue.